# How to clone bootstrap multi-select dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(function() {
  $('#days').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
  
  $('#btnSelected').click(function() {
    var selected = $("#days option:selected");
    var message = "";
    selected.each(function() {
      message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
    });
    document.write(message);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<select id="days" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">thusday</option>
  <option value="2">sunday</option>
  <option value="3">monday</option>
  <option value="4">tuesday</option>
  <option value="5">friday</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />
<button type="button" id="btn">+ Add Another Set OF Hourse
</button>
```

I am trying to do something like that when I click on add more button, multi-select drop-down will be cloned. And whenever, I click on submit it will show me selected values of all the multi-select(s).

Comment: some bootstrap-multiselect link you must add..for run the code proper

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Your question is not clear enough! Can you describe it little more?

Comment: And new dropdown will contain only selected values, right?

Comment: with every click on "+ Add Another "  one more multi-select drop-down was add after first ,like example.. i select some "days" from (first) multi-select drop-down without click on "get selected" button .....i click on   "+ Add Another.." so  (second) multi-select drop-down appear and select  some days for the second ...and do same for creating some more multi-select drop-down with click "+add more" after...... click on "get selected" all selected days of all "multi-drop" are display on after one....like what ever i code is only one dropdown multi data was display..please help me sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added functionality to clone multi-select on clicking the add button. Moreover, I have modified selection method to get selected values from all the multi-select drop-down.

```js
$('#days').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true
});

var i = 1;
$('#btnAddAnother').click(function(){
  var clone_multiselect = $("#days").clone();
  clone_multiselect.attr('id', 'days' + i);
  clone_multiselect.appendTo(".multiselect_container");

  $(clone_multiselect).multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

  i++;
});
  
$('#btnGetSelected').click(function() {
  $('.results').empty();
  $('select.multiselect').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var selected_option_selector = '#' + id + ' option:selected';
    var result_str = '<b>' + id + '</b>: ';

    $(selected_option_selector).each(function(){
      result_str += $(this).text() + ' - ' + $(this).val() + ', ';
    });

    result_str = result_str.substring(0, result_str.length - 2);
    result_str += '<br />';
    $('.results').append(result_str);
  });
});
```

```css
.results {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<div class="multiselect_container">
    <select id="days" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">thusday</option>
      <option value="2">sunday</option>
      <option value="3">monday</option>
      <option value="4">tuesday</option>
      <option value="5">friday</option>
    </select>
</div>

<br />
<button id="btnGetSelected" class="btn btn-primary">Get Selected</button>
<button id="btnAddAnother" class="btn btn-primary">+ Add Another Set OF Hourse</button>

<div class="results"></div>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gmq37n0s/)

Comment: @nab, Is this what you want?

Comment: yes sir that's what i want.thank you but i can not arrange this code so sir please help me my my e-id is (nab92.06@gmail.com)

Comment: What do you mean by arrange?

Comment: i put jquery and html code but its not working as work in snippet so i'm not able to properly arrange code as you actual code sir.help me sir.

Comment: Ok, can you email (`parkash-kumar@hotmail.com`) your complete HTML code to me?

Comment: it's just my some silly mistake your code is perfectly work thank you so much sir.for helping me.