# Dynamic multiselect feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating the fields dynamically in HTML using this JS, and in multiselect I'm using bootstrap multiselect here is the code https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekd8P when I click on the add more button it creates the form dynamically.

js code for creating a form dynamically :

```
$(function() {
  // Remove button 
  $(document).on(
    'click',
    '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-horizontal [data-role="remove"]',
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('.form-horizontal').remove();
    }
  );
  // Add button 
  var i = 1;
  $(document).on(
    'click',
    '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-horizontal [data-role="add"]',
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
      new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-horizontal:first-child').clone();

      new_field_group.find('input').each(function() {

        if (this.name == 'tags[0]') {
          $(this).tagsinput('destroy');
          $(this).tagsinput('removeAll');
          this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']');
          var new_container = $(this).closest('[class="form-group"]');
          new_container.find(".bootstrap-tagsinput:first").remove();
        } else {
          $(this).val('');
        }
      });
      new_field_group.find('select').each(function() {

        if (this.name == 'addons[0]') {

          $(this).multiselect('rebuild');
          this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']');
          var new_container = $(this).closest('[class="multiselect-native-select"]');
          new_container.find(".multiselect-native-select > .multi").remove();

        } else {
          $(this).val('');
        }

      });

      i += 1;
      container.append(new_field_group);
    }
  );
});
```

and html code for form elements:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-3">Enter Dish Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name1" name="Name[]" required data-rule-minlength="2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-3">Enter Dish Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Price" name="Price[]" required data-rule-minlength="2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-3">Select Food Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select id="select1" class="form-control" name="select[]" required>
                @foreach($types as $type)
                <option value="{{$loop->iteration}}">{{$type->food_type_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
              <p class="help-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="xyz"><i class="md md-info"></i></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-3">Dish Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea name="Description[]" id="field-value" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 contacts">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3" for="rolename">Add Addons</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ak form-control" name="addons[0]" id="trigger3" data-role="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach($addons as $addon)
                <option value="{{$addon->addonid}}">{{$addon->addon_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Firstname5" class="col-sm-3">Enter Tags</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" value="" name="tags[0]" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="e.g. spicy, healthy" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
              <label><em>Half Plate Price</em>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" class="trigger2" id="trigger2" name="question">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="hidden_fields2" class="hidden_fields2" style="display:none;">
              <input type="text" id="hidden_field2" name="Price2[]" placeholder="Please Enter" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
              <label><em>Quarter Plate Price</em>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" class="trigger" id="trigger" name="question">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="hidden_fields" class="hidden_fields" style="display:none;">
              <input type="text" id="hidden_field" name="Price3[]" placeholder="Please Enter" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Field" data-role="remove">
        Delete Item
      </button>
      <button class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add More Field" data-role="add">
        Add More Items
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- /div.form-inline -->
  </div>
  <!-- /div[data-role="dynamic-fields"] -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" href="#" class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary" style="margin-top: -62px;margin-left: 160px;">Submit Items</button>
  </div>
  <!--end .form-group -->
</form>
```

The issue is that when I click on the add more item it reflects the multiselect dropdown twice [image] as you see in this image.

I want that if I click on the add more item button it restates the multiselect dropdown as in the first state.

see this [jsfiddle.net/akshaycic/svv742r7/7](http://jsfiddle.net/akshaycic/svv742r7/7/) it will clear all your doubt. on click plus button it is not reflect to "none selected" state it will remain in its initial state.

Any leads would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the relevant output HTML (not source HTML) and Script only, preferably in a working snipped that demonstrates your issue in isolation?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/akshaycic/svv742r7/7/ it will clear all your doubt. on click plus button it is not reflect to "none selected" state it will remain in its initial state.
thank you

Comment: You seem to have several issues, first, when cloning you need to either specify that you also want to clone the events along with the markup you are cloning or re-initialize the multiselect on the cloned markup after injecting it into your container or your new multiselect is just markup with no events. See `clone()` documentation for more details: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ • Then there seems to be an issue with the context of items on cloned multiselects as selecting, unselecting options in the new multiselect changes your original select instead.

Comment: This possible duplicate of [**How to clone bootstrap multi-select dynamically?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527455/how-to-clone-bootstrap-multi-select-dynamically) contains a fiddle in the answer which works as the clones are re-initialized as needed which also sets the context of the new multiselect as expected. You can derive your solution from that.